# UITableview displays limited cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is setup correct and at some point I wanted
to display only a limited amount of cells. Now that I want to revert back
the functionality I am unable to do so.

The property that limits the visible cells (according to my git log):

```
// This will remove extra separators from tableview
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

After removing the above line, I still do not get the desired effect.

But something was introduced, and I am not sure what to search for.

**I want the default behavior back with many empty cells.**

Here is my methods for the sections and data, currently I only have
two cells visible.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [data count];
}
```

**View Hierarchy Debugging data.**

I am adding images of the View Debugger, "Wire Frame View" and "Content View" seperately.

From the images you will see two types of separator lines;
I mimicked a line by adding space at the bottom of the cell
so that I could have "thin lines".

[image: Wire Frame View]

[image: Content View]

Comment: Have you tried removing this line? what is the result after removing this line?

Comment: Removing the line has no effect.

Comment: I have updated my question, to give some more context.

Comment: self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];  This line will simply set the footerview to size zero, i don.t think it has nothing to do with the limited cell

Comment: The number of object in your data will be number of cell in your tableview.

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of what you are getting and what you expect?

Comment: Updated the question with more View "Debug Data"

Comment: I have created a new TableViewController and hooked up the StoryBoard to use the new ViewController this works, so there is some code that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `tableview` `height`. I think height of the table currently you are seeing is less so you are getting only 2 visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

As one can see from the attached images, the wire frames show that the separators are in fact drawn but they are not visibly on the screen when you view the content.

Simply change the colors:

```
  self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```